# How to launch a URL and get the callback to activity in Android

Tags: android, url, callback, retrofit2

I'm a bit lost with this feature.

I have to create a token request. Then, when I have this token, I have to launch a url with this provisional token, to allow the user login with his account and allow the app to use his account. But here is what I have the problem. I don't have clear how can achive this.

(I'm using TMBD API)
[image]

For example, the first step ( I did it wiht Retrofit2 )

```
@GET("authentication/token/new")
Observable<TokenResponseTMDB> getNewTemporaryToken(@Query("api_key") String apikey);

@Override
    public void getTemporaryToken() {
        Observable<TokenResponseTMDB> tokenResponseTMDBObservable = serviceTMDB.getNewTemporaryToken(API_KEY);
        tokenResponseTMDBObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<TokenResponseTMDB>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Logger.d(temporaryToken);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Logger.e(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(TokenResponseTMDB tokenResponseTMDB) {
                        temporaryToken = tokenResponseTMDB.getRequestToken();
                    }
                });
    }
```

But now, I don't know how to do step 2. I mean, I can call the url with the token like this:

```
String url = "https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/"+token;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

But I'm not sure if ca be done with retrofit, and how can I handle the Authentication header that is  said in the guide

> If they aren't redirected to a custom URL, the page will also have a
>   Authentication-Callback header. This header contains the API call for
>   step #3. You can either manually generate it or simply use the one we
>   return.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem too. This is how I solved it.

1. First step is easy and you almost did it already. First you have to make a call for request token, and once you get it, start a WebView. I have used a new Activity for this step, but you can stay in the same Activity/Fragment.

   ```
   Call<Token> call = mTmdbInterface.getToken(BuildConfig.TMDB_APIKEY);
   call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {

       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("token",response.body().getRequestToken());
           startActivityForResult(intent, 11);
       } 

       public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {

       }
   });
   ```
2. You should launch the Webview with the following link: "https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/" + token. The rest of this step is nothing you should worry about as App developer, you should just wait for the login part to finish, and wait for the redirect link which by default contains: "/allow".
   So you use that to notify your app that the user login part is done and finish the WebView and the WebActivity, so you can go to your Activity/Fragment where it all started.

   ```
   public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

       String token;
       WebView webView;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

           token = getIntent().getExtras().getString("token");

           webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
           webView.loadUrl("https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/" + token);
           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

               @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                   view.loadUrl(url);
                   return false;
               }

               @Override
               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                   super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                   if (url.contains("/allow")){
                       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           Intent intent = new Intent();
                           intent.putExtra("token", token);
                           setResult(11, intent);
                           finish();
                           }
                       }, 1000);

                   }
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. On this step, in your starting Activity/Fragment you use your authenticated token to get the session id. And thats it.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if(requestCode == 11) {

           Call<Session> call = mTmdbInterface.getSessionId(BuildConfig.TMDB_APIKEY, data.getExtras().getString("token"));
           call.enqueue(new Callback<Session>() {

               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<Session> call, Response<Session> response{
                   displayProfile(response.body().getSessionId());
               }    

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<Session> call, Throwable t) {

               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

I hope it helps to someone else if you have already made it.
I dont know if this is best practice, but this is the way I did it and it works fine for me.